# How do I find out what app is using a specific shortcut, in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I want to use a specific shortcut to archive my Mail on macOS, Command+Shift+A, but even thought it lets me add it in the keyboard shortcuts section, it doesnt do anything when I go in Mail. i got a feeling some third-party app is using it, or something else, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Anyone come across this and have any ideas?

Comment: Is it recognised as having been changed in the Message menu itself? [From the default ⌃ ⌘ A ]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When i look in the menu dropdown in Mail it shows `⌃ ⌘ A`. So im not sure why it doesnt conform

Comment: If it never changes in the menu itself, it wasn't set up correctly. Even though that shortcuts pref will not warn you of conflicts it will still alter the menu visually. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcTQq.jpg